# Erro ao criar Google Maps Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mobile

Quando crio no meu projeto um **new -> Google -> Google Maps Activity** ele cria tudo corretamente.

---

Então adiciono a chave em `google_maps_api.xml`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    chave . . .
</string>
```

---

Entretanto, quando vou compilar o projeto apresenta o seguinte **erro**:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 37.338 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

---

Ele coloca automaticamente nas dependencias (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0')

Se eu mudar para a versão 8.4.0(compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') ele para de dar o erro porém quando entro na Activity do mapa, ele não aparece. aparece apenas o logo da google no canto inferior esquerdo da tela.

Comment: Não consegue adicionar o stack trace completo?

Comment: Opa, atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cristian,

Da uma olhada no seu **AndroidManifest.xml**

Você vai reparar lááá no final que está assim:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Você precisa registrar essa **KEY** lá no Dashboard no Google, você vai precisar do SHA-1 da sua máquina de desenvolvimento.

Da uma pesquisada em como gerar a KEY HASH para o Google Maps.

Espero ter ajudado,
Abraços.

Comment: A chave eu adicionei.
O mais estranho é que quando crio direto pelo Android Studio, automaticamente ele acrescenta a dependencia (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0') mas se eu colocar com versão 8.4.0 (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') ele não apresenta o erro porem quando entro o mapa não aparece, apenas o logo na google no canto inferior direito da tela.